# How can I count how many diverse item in the column 'item'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I count how many diverse items in the column 'item'?

```
               item
index
0              lm792
1       sotl085-pu01
2              lm792
3       sotl085-pu01
4          ym11-3527
            ...     
9991        Hang tag
9992        Hang tag
9993        Hang tag
9994          Thread
9995          Thread
```

Comment: Do you want to know how many total diverse items are there or how many of each diverse items are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe name is df, you could do

```py
print(len(pd.unique(df.item)))
print(len(df.item.unique()))
```

Basically you create a list of unqiue items and then get the length of list. Documentation is here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df.item.value_counts()
```

(Assuming your dataframe is named `df`).

Comment: To add to the above: `dict(df.item.value_counts())` might prove helpful too.

Comment: @SamChats Good answer. If the OP wants to know total of diverse items then you have to pass say len(df.item.value_counts()). However if the intention was to know counts of each unique item then your answer is the way to go :-). I have asked the OP this clarity.